# Is there a way to let the enum return the value without method

Tags: java, enums

If this is my enum:

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (3.303e+23),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26);

    private final double mass;   // in kilograms

    Planet(double mass) {
        this.mass = mass;
    }
    private double mass() { 
        return mass; 
    }
}
```

I can access the values like

```
Planet.MERCURY.mass();
```

**Is there the chance to define the enum as "double" and let**

```
Planet.MERCURY;
```

**return a double?**

Anyway I'm mainly interested in the appearance of the call to ensure code readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is not possible with Java representation of enums. Personally I find `Planet.MERCURY.mass()` much more readable.

The only thing that comes to my mind slightly increasing the readability is making the mass `public final` instead of `private final` and refer to `Planet.MERCURY.mass` but I would give it some second thoughts.

Comment: but if there's just one parameter and I only want to fix a set of objects and give them "groups" and "names" I don't need those methods...

Comment: @Wojtek what's the disadvantage of making it public final?

Comment: @Frank what if some time in the future you will decide that mass() should return some other units instead of kilos. If you have a getter you can easily implement that logic in the body of the method.

Comment: @Wojtek i could simply add another getter... but in general i don't mind about those brackets I just miss the possibility to receive the value by calling the object

Answer (score 0):

You can define class instead of enum:

```
public static class Planet {
    public static final double MERCURY = 3.303e+23;
}
```

Now you can obtain value:

```
Planet.MERCURY
```

But with enum it is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: I thought of that but scraped it due to a lack of usability (switch for instance)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in appearance, then I highly suggest using your current implementation with `Planet.MERCURY.mass()`. You can not get more readable. I have the tendency too to try to shorten code as much as possible. But over the years I have found that this just introduces more problems. If you want to use the mass of mercury in long formulae that you want to keep somewhat readable, you can just locally do

```
double mMerc = Planet.MERCURY.mass();
// other local temp variables

double distance = Math.sqrt(G*mMerc*mRocket/F);
```

or so. This approach also enables you to later add more constants very easily (like distanceToSun, surfaceTemperature, eccentricity, albedo, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Also you could return the mass as a String, but it will only work in string concatenations and methods that expects a String as an argument, like `System.out.println()` or `String.format()`

```
public enum Planet {
   MERCURY (3.303e+23),
   NEPTUNE (1.024e+26);

   private final double mass;   // in kilograms

   Planet(double mass) {
      this.mass = mass;
   }
   private double mass() { 
      return mass; 
   }

   public String toString() { 
      return String.valueOf(mass);
   }
}
```

I agree with the previous answers/comments that the verbose `.mass()` method is a more readable/maintainable solution

Also, you could avoid using an enum, an declare constans container class, like this:

```
public class Planet { 
    public final static double MERCURY = 3.303e+23;
    public final static double NEPTUNE = 1.024e+26;
    // .... 

    // Make 'Planet' not easily instantiable for others
    private Planet() {}
}
```

And like this you could use Planet.MERCURY as a double without problem